# easy and simple way to test/automate Android app

Tags: automation

There is an app that I need to automate. I only have the APK, I do know there is UIAutomator, but there is not much info about how it can be used with an APK (no source code). Are are some tools available to automate a simple process on Android?

Comment: You added the tag `automation` to your question, and there are over 200 questions associated with that tag. Have you investigated those? Hover over the tag and click the link `view tag` to take you to a list of related questions to explore.

Comment: Simple?  No.  If you know some basic-level programming, however, you can research Appium

Comment: @BillHileman thanks for the suggestion. i got Appium installed. Do you know any examples written in java for the uiautomator2 driver?

Comment: Search for Guru99.  It's a learning site and they have a short example on learning Appium